# convert a tuple with three elements into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

This is my tuple

```
(0, 7, 4)
(1, 7, 4)
(2, 7, 4)
(3, 7, 4)
(0, 4, 1)
(0, 4, 3)
(0, 6, 4)
```

I want to convert this to a dictionary for for an example

```
{0:(7,4), (4, 1), (4, 3), (6, 4), 1: (7, 4), 2:(7, 4), ....}
```

basically first element of the tuple is key and second and third elements are values.

The tuple was generated using :

```
for i in range(len(vertices)): 
     #print(i) 
     for j in edges: 
     d= (i, j[0], j[1]) 
     print(d)
```

Comment: Is taht a list of tuples or what exactly is your input?

Comment: No that is not list of tuple. It is generated using a for loop.   for i in range(len(vertices)):
        #print(i)
        for j in edges:
            d= (i, j[0], j[1])
            print(d)

Comment: @lpt the code in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593764/convert-a-tuple-with-three-elements-into-dictionary#comment92122438_52593764) belongs to the question. Could you plese [edit] your question including the code?  Moreover, I doubt that the code you have posted can produce the data you have presented.  Eventually, please take into account that  you can create the requested dictionary directly inside the loop (if it were correct as posted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing this

```
print ((i, j[0], j[1]))
```

you could also do

```
dict[i] = (j[0], j[1])
```

however, that won't work with repeating indexes. So let me think of a better way...

#### update

after reviewing, the way to go is to use `setdefault` (as previously mentioned in another answer), in order to provide something different to the other answer, I show the long way around it:

```
dictionary = d()
for i in range(len(vertices)): 
    for j in edges:             
        if i in d:
           d[i].append((j[0], j[1]))
        else:
           d[i] = (j[0], j[1])
```

-----Improved which works----

```
dictionary = dict()
    for i in range(len(vertices)): 
        for j in edges: 
            d= (i, j[0], j[1])
            dictionary[i]=[]
            #print(d) 
            if i in dictionary :
    
                #print(dictionary[i])
                dictionary[i].append((j[0], j[1]),)
            else:
                dictionary[i] = (j[0], j[1])
    print(dictionary)
```

Comment: it generates tuple cannot be appended message, here dictionary[i].append((j[0], j[1])).  Trying to think find solution here. I think that would work after that solution

Comment: but if I comment out the append part, it generates dictionary on "else" condition.

Comment: ok, the you could also use collections.defaultdict, was trying to avoid it but it you could give it a try

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following loop to append to a dict of lists:

```
d = {}
for k, *v in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(tuple(v))
```

so that given:

```
l = [
    (0, 7, 4),
    (1, 7, 4),
    (2, 7, 4),
    (3, 7, 4),
    (0, 4, 1),
    (0, 4, 3),
    (0, 6, 4)
]
```

`d` would become:

```
{0: [(7, 4), (4, 1), (4, 3), (6, 4)], 1: [(7, 4)], 2: [(7, 4)], 3: [(7, 4)]
```

Comment: how would you convert those lists eg  [7, 4], [4, 1]  to tuples.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it converts them to tuples instead.

Comment: well l is not the list in my case, I generated using for loop. itertools's chain wont put that into one list.

Comment: `l` can be any iterable, not just a list. Or you can easily use the `list()` constructor to convert an iterable to a list.

Comment: Or if you want to apply this to an existing `for` loop where you already have a tuple `t` generated from each iteration, you can do `k, *v = t` before you do `d.setdefault(k, []).append(tuple(v))`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from itertools import groupby


a =  [(0, 7, 4), (1, 7, 4), (2, 7, 4), (3, 7, 4), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 3), (0, 6, 4)]
l={} 
for i,g in groupby(a, lambda x:x[0]): 
    l[str(i)] = []  
    for v in g: 
        l[str(i)].append(v[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the code you've posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593764/convert-a-tuple-with-three-elements-into-dictionary#comment92122438_52593764) is correct, but it is possible to fill the dictionary directly inside the loop

```
d = {}                         
for i in range(len(vertices)): 
    d[i] = []              
    for j in edges:        
        d[i].append((j[0], j[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
l = [
    (0, 7, 4),
    (1, 7, 4),
    (2, 7, 4),
    (3, 7, 4),
    (0, 4, 1),
    (0, 4, 3),
    (0, 6, 4)]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
l = [(x, (y, z)) for x, y, z in l]
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
d = {key: list(list(zip(*tup))[1]) for key, tup in groupby(l, itemgetter(0))}
```